# Error: An aggregate may not appear UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, join, temp-tables

I am trying to update the Column of my Temp Table using following query:

```
Update T
Set T.ConsumedQuantity  = SUM(MA.Quantity)
from @TempTable T
Join DefaultShopView DSV on DSV.OperationId =@OpId
join MySpec MS with(nolock) on MS.WorkRequest = DSV.WorkRequest
join MyActual MA with(nolock) on MA.SpecId = MS.SpecId
```

But getting the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

How do I then update the values?

Comment: Which dbms? (Syntax far from ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: @jarlh, it seems T-SQL: [An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
(Msg 157, Level 15, State 1).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/90477)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Update T
Set T.ConsumedQuantity  = (select SUM(MA.Quantity) from @TempTable
            Join DefaultShopView DSV on DSV.OperationId =@OpId
            join MySpec MS with(nolock) on MS.WorkRequest = DSV.WorkRequest
            join MyActual MA with(nolock) on MA.SpecId = MS.SpecId ) 
from @TempTable T
Join DefaultShopView DSV on DSV.OperationId =@OpId
join MySpec MS with(nolock) on MS.WorkRequest = DSV.WorkRequest
join MyActual MA with(nolock) on MA.SpecId = MS.SpecId
```

Comment: Why the Joins After  -- From @TempTable T

Answer (score 0):

Easiest using CTE:

```
;WITH CTE as (
    SELECT T.IDENTIFIERS_FIELDS, SUM(MA.Quantity) as MA_Sum
    from @TempTable T
    DefaultShopView DSV on DSV.OperationId =@OpId
    join MySpec MS with(nolock) on MS.WorkRequest = DSV.WorkRequest
    join MyActual MA with(nolock) on MA.SpecId = MS.SpecId 
    GROUP BY GROUPING_FIELDS_IF_ANY
)
Update T
Set T.ConsumedQuantity  = MA_Sum
from @TempTable T
Join CTE on T.IDENTIFIERS_FIELDS = CTE.IDENTIFIERS_FIELDS
```

Reading question is not clear if you need to grouping or not. Get this select as template to customize your final query.

Comment: What are IDENTIFIERS_FIELDS?

Comment: As I say in comment is not clear your database schema. If you need a different `sum(MA.QTY)` for each `@TempTable` row then you must include `@TempTable` identifiers fields on CTE query to allow join in update sentence. The same for `GROUPING_FIELDS_IF_ANY`.